# how to send json data under passport local strategy

Tags: node.js, callback, passport.js, passport-local

This is my passport Login Handler.

Now I want to send JSON Data under every condition so that API can access the response and on behalf of this display anything on frontend.

```
//Login Handler
passport.use('local-user', new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.getUserByUsername(username, function(err, user){
        if(err) {
            console.log('error')
            logger.log('error', 'Error Generates on User.getUserByUsername Query on users.js file');
            throw err;
        }
        if(!user){
            //res.send('unknown user');
            console.log('Unknown User');
            return done(null, false, {message: 'Unknown User'});
        }
        User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch){
            if(err) {
                logger.log('error', 'Error Generates on User.comparePassword Query on users.js file');
                throw err;
            }
            if(isMatch){
                return done(null, user);
            }else{
                return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid Credential, please check carefully...!'})
            }
        });
    });
  }
));
```

Anyone have any idea for this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you show us you endpoint for login?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The local strategy will pass the user or error with done(), then you receive that with a callback and pack it with res.json()

Here is my implementation. May help?

```
passport.use(
      new LocalStrategy(
        {
          usernameField: "email"
        },
        function(username, password, done) {
          User.findOne({ email: username }, function(err, user) {
            if (err) {
              return done(err);
            }
            if (!user) {
              return done(null, false, {
                email: "Email not found"
              });
            }
            if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
              return done(null, false, {
                password: "Password is wrong"
              });
            }
            return done(null, user);
          });
        }
      )
    );

    router.post("/login", function(req, res) {
      passport.authenticate("local", function(err, user, info) {
        if (err) {
          res.status(404).json(err);
          return;
        }

        if (user) {
          const token = user.generateJwt();
          res.status(200);
          res.json({
            userInfo: user,
            token: token
          });
        } else {
          res.status(401).json(info);
        }
      })(req, res);
    });
```

Comment: It works... Please tell about the callback argument i.e info?

Comment: info is the custom error message passed by the passport's done function. For example, "password is wrong" is set as a third variable to done right?

Comment: I had an issue. By this method req and response is send but my session is not set. my previous method is automatically stored the session. Why this one not doing. Any idea??

Comment: Ah, yes I do. In my implementation, JWT is used. I'm not using sessions. This article may help. (https://www.sitepoint.com/passport-authentication-for-nodejs-applications/)